# Enumerable.Range in and Expression and Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0, expression

I'm currently developping an expression method (used in linq to entity queries) who has to give me

- a daycount for a given period (start date and end date)
- decrementing this daycount if specials days are in the period.

My idea was the following :

- Generate an enumerable with all the dates (and with Enumerable.Range)
- Make a .Where on this enumerable to remove the specials dates Like a MyEnumerable.Where(a => a != "20120101")
- After that, return a MyEnumerable.Count()

I come with this code :

```
return (p) => Enumerable
                  .Range(1, 4)
                  .Where(a => a != 20120101)  
                  .AsQueryable()
                  .Count()
```

I tried to cast as a list, as a queryable, both (like the example) and no way ! it doesn't work ! I always get this error :

**LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32] Range(Int32, Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.**

Have you got an idea about that ?
Using an enumerable is of course not mandatory, any working solutions is good ^^

Thank's by advance !

To simplify my question, this don't works and i want to.

```
(
  from foo in User 
  select new 
  { 
    a = Enumerable.Range(1,4).Count() 
  }
).Take(1)
```

---

More informations :-)

If i do this (externalize the enumerable in a variable) :

```
var foo = Enumerable.Range(1, 4);
return (p) => foo.Where(a => a != 20110101).Count();
```

This time it works, but i can't define the range start and end with this method !

Comment: The error message doesn't make sense without some additional context.  It refers to Linq to Entities, but nothing in your code or description explains where that is coming from.

Comment: The problem must have something do with `User`, because if `var User = "asdf";`, then your code works fine.

Comment: In this case, User is an DbSet

Comment: Where are stored your special days? DB or Code?

Comment: It appears that you are trying to hide parts of the query and in so doing are blocking the real source of your issue. Ultimately, you can't mix custom code in your EF query the way you are trying to. Filter the core results you want and then cast .ToEnumerable then perform your custom date generator on the enumerable version.

Comment: Yep, it seems that this is a too complicated for the desired goal. I'll try your way. Thank's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below generates a real DateTime range and will therefore correctly handle leap years, varying month ends, and so on. It also correctly handles daysToExclude being null or empty.

```
DateTime baseDate = DateTime.Now;
DateTime[] daysToExclude = new DateTime[] { new DateTime(2012, 6, 25), new DateTime(2012, 6, 30) } ;
int numberOfDays = baseDate.AddMonths(1).Subtract(baseDate).Days;

int days = Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfDays).Select(day => baseDate.Date.AddDays(day)).Except(daysToExclude ?? Enumerable.Empty<DateTime>()).Count();
```